# NameError: name "['Row ID', 'Order ID', 'Ship Date'...] not found in axis"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
cols = ['Row ID', 'Order ID', 'Order Date', 'Ship Date', 'Ship Mode',
        'Customer ID', 'Customer Name', 
        'Segment', 'Country', 'City', 'State',
        'Postal Code', 'Region', 'Product ID',
        'Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Product Name',
        'Quantity', 'Discount', 'Profit']
furniture.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
furniture = furniture.sort_values('Order Date')
furniture.isnull().sum()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85GBX.png)

KeyError: "['Row ID', 'Order ID', 'Ship Date', 'Ship Mode', 'Customer ID', 'Customer Name', 'Segment', 'Country', 'City', 'State', 'Postal Code', 'Region', 'Product ID', 'Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Product Name', 'Quantity', 'Discount', 'Profit'] not found in axis"

'I tried removing error fixing the import lib such as pandas as well as numpy but its not doing anything as well as its keep giving me same erroe and not letting define colum.'

Comment: _"...and not letting define colum"_ - Are you trying to define new columns or drop existing ones? Because Pandas is telling you one or more of the axes you provided don't exist in your dataframe.

Comment: What contains the variable 'furniture'? Could you add the lines of code where you create it?

Comment: Why do you want to drop the `Order Date` and then sort on it immediately after you get rid of it? That will just cause another KeyError.

Comment: @ 
DSantiagoB df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\savan\Downloads\Superstore.xls")
furniture = df.loc[df['Category']=='Furniture']
furniture['Order Date'].min(), furniture['Order Date'].max()

Comment: @it_is_Chris 
even if I don't drop it it still gives me the same error.